# Jackson not throwing an exception on deserializing when provided json is different class type than targeted class

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization, json-deserialization

I have two classes `A` and `B`, both having public getters and constructors marked with `@JsonCreator` and `@JsonProperty` on constructor arguments. Both of those classes are deserialized correctly when correct json is provided. However when I provide a json that is a projection of class type A and try to deserialize it into B type object, I expect an exception to be thrown. It turnes out that jackson deserializes json correctly into B type object, but this object is just null. Is this the default behaviour? My `ObjectMapper` is created simply with `new ObjectMapper()`. Can I configure it in any way so that it throws an exception in described case?

Class A implementation:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
final class A {

    private final String propertyA;

    @JsonCreator
    A(@JsonProperty("propertyA") String propertyA) {
        this.propertyA = propertyA;
    }

    public String getPropertyA() {
        return propertyA;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "A{" +
            "propertyA='" + propertyA + '\'' +
            '}';
    }

}
```

Class B implementation:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
final class B {

    private final String propertyB;

    @JsonCreator
    B(@JsonProperty("propertyB") String propertyB) {
        this.propertyB = propertyB;
    }

    public String getPropertyB() {
        return propertyB;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "B{" +
            "propertyB='" + propertyB + '\'' +
            '}';
    }

}
```

Json with class B projection: `{"propertyB":"propertyBValue"}`

Deserialization code:

```
String jsonWithBObject = "{\"propertyB\":\"propertyBValue\"}";

A deserializedAObject = mapFromJsonToObject(jsonWithBObject, A.class);
```

```
private <T> T mapFromJsonToObject(String json, Class<T> targetClass) {
    try {
        return objectMapper.readValue(json, targetClass);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException exception) {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
```

And after running this code, no exception is thrown, and `deserializdAObject` contains: `A{propertyA='null'}`

Comment: Can you please show your class A and B and json and the code you have written to deserialize your Jason?

Comment: @akash I updated the post with code samples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `@JsonProperty(required = true)` to force Jackson throw exception on missing key

**This property is only partially supported**. Excerpt from Jackson javadoc:

> ```
>  Note that as of 2.6, this property is only used for Creator
>  Properties, to ensure existence of property value in JSON:
>  for other properties (ones injected using a setter or mutable
>  field), no validation is performed. Support for those cases
>  may be added in future.
> ```

Comment: Not sure though if it actually works as expected, I recall there were some gaps in implementation.

Comment: It does work exactly as I need, an exception is thrown, because the required field is missing and I kept ```@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)```.

Answer (score 1):

`@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` is causing jackson to ignore the unknown properties and the object you get after deserialization is the one with all attributes initialised with default values (which is `null` for non-primitives).

Use `required=true` to force Jackson to throw exception in case property is missing.

```java
 @JsonCreator
    B(@JsonProperty(value="propertyB", required=true) String propertyB) {
        this.propertyB = propertyB;
    }
```

Comment: I see, that makes sense. However in my program, so called ```class A``` has to have the ```@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)``` because the actual response contains much more properties which I don't need. Can I somehow maintain the  ```@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)``` and handle json with wrong projection class just as I described in my question?